# GridView in ASP.net using wrong date format MM/DD/YYYY instead of DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView in ASP.net which is filled from an SqlDataSource.

one of the columns in the DB table is a Datetime which is set to 30/04/2009, when i show the grid view in asp it appears as 30/04/2009.(which is fine)

however when I hit edit on the row in the grid view, and then hit update without changing the date I get an SQL error which says essentially that the date format is wrong. This is because it thinks that the 30 is refering to the month rather than the day.

I have tried resolving this by setting the <%@ Page uiCulture="en-gb" culture="en-gb" %>

but with no effect.

any ideas?

Comment: What is the update parameter's type? (DateTime, string, or undeclared?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When date is bound to GridView, it is already a `String` and no more a `DateTime`. I suggest you set the `DataFormatString` of the column to `{0:d}`, which will display the date based on the page UI.

Answer (score 1):

most probably it is not page's culture but culture settings in SQL Server that are causing problems.

Comment: but it seems to work fine in the db, for example i can add a date 30/04/09 to the column in the database but i cant add 04/30/09